# How to import .xtend files into Android Activity Class?

Tags: android, xtend

For one of my POC, I am using ClassName.xtend files for some functionality. Whenevenr I am tring to import that class(ClassName.xtend) into my activity it showing error and not importing that xtend files. Please any one help me to import the xtend file to my activity and run my application

```
package com.tobykurien.webapps
```

import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem
import android.view.WindowManager
import android.widget.ListView
import com.tobykurien.webapps.data.Webapp
import com.tobykurien.webapps.db.DbService
import com.tobykurien.webapps.fragment.DlgOpenUrl
import java.util.List
import org.xtendroid.adapter.BeanAdapter
import org.xtendroid.annotations.AndroidView

import static extension com.tobykurien.webapps.utils.Dependencies.*
import static extension org.xtendroid.utils.AlertUtils.*

class MainActivity extends Activity {
   @AndroidView ListView mainList
   var List webapps

override protected onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

```
  if (settings.isFullscreen()) {
     getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                             WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
  }      

  setContentView(R.layout.main)
```

}

override protected onStart() {
      super.onStart()

```
  val activity = this
  loadWebapps

  mainList.setOnItemClickListener([av, v, pos, id|
     var intent = new Intent(activity, typeof(WebAppActivity))
     intent.action = Intent.ACTION_VIEW
     intent.data = Uri.parse(webapps.get(pos).url)
     intent.putExtra(BaseWebAppActivity.EXTRA_WEBAPP_ID, id)
     startActivity(intent)
  ])

  mainList.setOnItemLongClickListener([av, v, pos, id|
     confirm(getString(R.string.delete_webapp), [|
        db.execute(R.string.dbDeleteDomains, #{'webappId' -> id})
        db.delete(DbService.TABLE_WEBAPPS, String.valueOf(id))
        loadWebapps
     ])
     true
  ])
```

}

override onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu)
      true
   }

override onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
      switch (item.itemId) {
         case R.id.menu_open: {
            var dlg = new DlgOpenUrl()
            dlg.show(fragmentManager, "open_url")
         }
         case R.id.menu_settings: {
            var i = new Intent(this, typeof(Preferences))
            startActivity(i)
         }
         case R.id.menu_exit: finish()
      }
      super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
   }

def loadWebapps() {
      webapps = db.getWebapps
      var adapter = new BeanAdapter(this, R.layout.row_webapp, webapps) 
      mainList.setAdapter(adapter)
   }
}

[image]
Thanks

Comment: I can't really help you on this little information. Could you please show some code and especially the error message. A simple example on Github would be awesome.

Comment: @Krishna you should import as usual java class in your case it's `import ClassName`. Or check your project source path

Comment: @Helpa I tried like a usual java class but I am getting the following error The "import com.tobykurien.webapps.db.DbService cannot be 
 resolved"